# Basic JFrame Calculator

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Can someone explain why nothing is being displayed inside the application window when I run this?

It seems kind of weird,  I had it displaying the `JButton`s just fine until I added a couple more, then it seemed to have affected everything.

Here is my code:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    JButton zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine;
    JButton add, sub, mul, div, mod;
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JLabel results;

    public Window(){
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Calculator");
        this.setVisible(true);

        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        results = new JLabel("RESULTS");
        results.setToolTipText("Calculated Results");

        zero = new JButton("0");
        one = new JButton("1");
        two = new JButton("2");
        three = new JButton("3");
        four = new JButton("4");
        five = new JButton("5");
        six = new JButton("6");
        seven = new JButton("7");
        eight = new JButton("8");
        nine = new JButton("9");

        add = new JButton("+");
        sub = new JButton("-");
        mul = new JButton("*");
        div = new JButton("/");
        mod = new JButton("%");

        this.add(mainPanel);

        mainPanel.add(zero);
        mainPanel.add(one);
        mainPanel.add(two);
        mainPanel.add(three);
        mainPanel.add(four);
        mainPanel.add(five);
        mainPanel.add(six);
        mainPanel.add(seven);
        mainPanel.add(eight);
        mainPanel.add(nine);

        mainPanel.add(add);
        mainPanel.add(sub);
        mainPanel.add(mul);
        mainPanel.add(div);
        mainPanel.add(mod);

        mainPanel.add(results);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try adding a layout to your mainPanel, and move `setVisible(true);`  to the end of the constructor.

Comment: Creating the GUI on the main thread is not recommend. Use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(); with a Runnable instance.

Comment: @shivam7357 This is [not entirely true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156949/main-thread-vs-ui-thread-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

When you call `setVisible(true)`, your `JFrame` is rendered and displayed.

If you add stuff to it *after* that, those things will not be visible until you call `validate()`, `pack()` or `setVisible(true)` again.

- `validate()` re-validates your component. It is "invalidated" whenever you add stuff to it, like in your code. It has to re-validated for those changes to show up.
- `pack()` sizes your component (the `JFrame`), using any layout managers to calculate the sizes of it. It also re-validates it.
- `setVisible(true)` does just what it sounds like, but since it was already visible the interesting bit for you is that it also re-validates the component.

So, what you should do after adding the components:

1. Call `setVisible()`, or
2. Call `validate()`

The second one only in case you actually want to dynamically add stuff to your panel, which I doubt in this case :)

Your code would look like this:

```
mainPanel.add(results);

pack();
setVisible(true);
```

And the earlier call to `setVisible()` (line 18) can be removed.

You might want to [add a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660751/java-swing-jframe-layout) to your window too, and the [Java™ Tutorial page on `JFrame`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) is probably useful.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code in this way:

```
        ....
        mainPanel.add(results);
        this.setVisible(true);//Move this line to this place(at the end)
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jad Chahine that's why I said "move the setVisible();"