# Why button is filling up the whole JFRAME

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have make this demo testing code but when ever i run this code the button covers whole frame and i have even tried SetBound method but still it do not work

```
package com.Testing.Java;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void Simple(){
        JFrame f=new JFrame();

        JButton b=new JButton("Click");
        b.setBounds(100,100,100,100);


        f.add(b);
        f.setSize(400,500);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLayout(null);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        Simple();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There's no need to use `<code>` - just indent the code (as you already had) and Markdown will take care of the rest.

Comment: default frame layout is border .so button is added to center and use entire frame.you add button before set layout

Comment: The default layout of the `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`. Your button gets added to `BorderLayout.CENTER`, so it takes the whole space. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660751/java-swing-jframe-layout

Comment: thanks that worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first don't use `null layout` .use layout managers

default frame layout is `border layout` .so button is added to center and use entire frame.you add button before set layout.

when you add first set layout then add component

like this

```
f.setLayout(null);
f.add(b);
```